# Why when using openFileDialog i don't see all the settings i changed?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In top of form1 i did

```
OpenFiledialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFiledialog();
```

Then:

```
private void changeWorkingDirectoryToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    openFileDialog1.Filter =  
"BMP|*.bmp|GIF|*.gif|JPG|*.jpg;*.jpeg|PNG|*.png|TIFF|*.tif;*.tiff|"
   + "All Graphics Types|*.bmp;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;*.tif;*.tiff";
    openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"c:\";
    openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string[] files = openFileDialog1.FileNames;

        try
        {
            if (files.Length > 0)
            {
                label6.Text = files.Length.ToString();
                label6.Visible = true;
                string directoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(files[0]);
                label12.Text = directoryPath;
                label12.Visible = true;
            }
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

But when i click the button the init directory is documents and not c: and i don't see the filter/s at all but i see all the files. It's like the settings i did didn't effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ShowDialog` is modal, so it waits until the user clicks OK/Cancel.

Only then does the rest of your code run.
You should only call `ShowDialog` after you have finished setting the properties:

```
openFileDialog1.Filter = "BMP|*.bmp|GIF|*.gif|JPG|*.jpg...";
openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"c:\";
openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;

DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
if (result == DialogResult.OK)
```

Answer (score 4):

Your logic is incorrect. You're displaying the dialog *before* you configure the settings.

```
// Configure it first
openFileDialog1.Filter = "BMP|*.bmp|GIF|*.gif|JPG|*.jpg;*.jpeg|PNG|*.png|TIFF|*.tif;*.tiff|"
   + "All Graphics Types|*.bmp;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;*.tif;*.tiff";
openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"c:\";
openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;

// Then show it and wait for the user to make a selection or cancel
DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

// Take some action if the user made a selection
if (result == DialogResult.OK)
{
    ...
```

As a side note, be careful about eating exceptions. At the least, log the error and inform the user.

```
catch (IOException ex)
{
    // log ex.ToString() somewhere

    MessageBox.Show("An error has occurred!\r\n\r\n" + ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are calling `ShowDialog()` before settings the properties, this should work for you:

```
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "BMP|*.bmp|GIF|*.gif|JPG|*.jpg;*.jpeg|PNG|*.png|TIFF|*.tif;*.tiff|"
       + "All Graphics Types|*.bmp;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;*.tif;*.tiff";

    openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"c:\";
    openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;

    DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string[] files = openFileDialog1.FileNames;

        try
        {
        if (files.Length > 0)
            {
                label6.Text = files.Length.ToString();
                label6.Visible = true;
                string directoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(files[0]);
                label12.Text = directoryPath;
                label12.Visible = true;
            }
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
        }
   }
```